# recommended Cloud Firestore location for saudi arabia audience

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, location, cloud

what is the recommended Cloud Firestore location for saudi arabia audience

i try to choose good and more near place to store data to provide perfect performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the available Firestore regions at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations

Your closest region would be located in Europe:

```
Europe
europe-west2    London
europe-west3    Frankfurt
europe-west6    Zürich
```

You can also try [gcping](https://www.gcping.com/) to test latencies to different Google Cloud regions.

Answer (score 0):

I will order the three areas based on the actual distance to Saudi Arabia.

europe-west6 Zürich = 4394 KM away from Saudi Arabia

europe-west3 Frankfurt = 4525 KM away from Saudi Arabia

europe-west2 London = 5151 KM away from Saudi Arabia

**So the nearest server is europe-west6 Zürich**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).